# Decomposition of $z^q-z$ with $q=p^n$ in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ with $|\mathbb{K}|=q$.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, quotient-group

Let $q=p^n$ be a prime power, and $\mathbb{K}$ a field of $q$ elements. We need to show that $z^q-z$ decomposes into linear polynomials in $\mathbb{K}[z]$. Have been reading notes all over and suspect I could use some stuff about Lagrange, but don't really know what to do with it. I know $z^q-z$ is the product of monic irreducible polynomials, but don't know how to show these are linear.

Comment: Changed my question a bit to make it about only one thing, and that link did orient me in the right direction but couldn't quite finalise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

- If $x\in K$ is not zero, what can you say about $x^{q-1}$ (Subhint: Lagrange) ?
- Deduce that every element of $K$ is a root of $P=z^q-z$
- Conclude.

Comment: I think you can say that $x^{q-1}=1$, but I still don't know how Lagrange helps. I've been thinking that $\mathbb{K}$ is the extension field of degree $n$ for a certain field $\mathbb{F}_p$ and with Lagrange, $p|p^n$ but I don't know how that helps :(

Comment: What gives Lagrange with the group $K^\times$ ?